# Converting dataframe column into multiple rows ,repeating values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, python-itertools

This is my CSV:

```
languages,    origin,     other_test1,       other_test2
"[{'name': 'French', 'vowel_count': 3}, {'name': 'Dutch', 'vowel_count': 4}, {'name': 'English', 'vowel_count': 5}]",Germanic,ABC,DEF
```

I want to convert languages column of CSV into following output:

```
Language_name ,Language_vowel_count, origin,    other.test1, other.test2
French,        3,                    Germanic,  ABC,         DEF
Dutch,         4,                    Germanic,  ABC,         DEF
English,       5,                    Germanic,  ABC,         DEF
```

Code that I tried:

```
 from itertools import chain

 a = df['languages'].str.findall("'(.*?)'").astype(np.object)
 lens = a.str.len()

  df = pd.DataFrame({
'origin' : df['origin'].repeat(lens),
'other_test1' : df['other_test1'].repeat(lens),
'other_test2' : df['other_test2'].repeat(lens),
'name' : list(chain.from_iterable(a.tolist())),
'vowel_count' : list(chain.from_iterable(a.tolist())),
})

df
```

But its not giving me the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to unpack the data, together with a `ast.literal_eval` to convert the JSON string into a python dictionary.

```
import ast

>>> pd.DataFrame(
    [[languages.get('name'), languages.get('vowel_count'), row['origin'], row['other_test1'], row['other_test2']]
     for idx, row in df.iterrows() 
     for languages in ast.literal_eval(row['languages'])],
    columns=['Language_name', 'Language_vowel_count', 'origin', 'other.test1', 'other.test2'])
  Language_name  Language_vowel_count    origin other.test1 other.test2
0        French                     3  Germanic         ABC         DEF
1         Dutch                     4  Germanic         ABC         DEF
2       English                     5  Germanic         ABC         DEF
```

An alternative method without using `iterrows` concatenates the unpacked languages with the base data:

```
languages = df['languages'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))

df_lang = pd.DataFrame(
    [(lang.get('name'), lang.get('vowel_count')) 
     for language in languages 
     for lang in language])

df_new = pd.concat([
    df_lang, 
    df.iloc[:, 1:].reindex(df.index.repeat([len(x) for x in languages])).reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

df_new.columns = ['Language_name', 'Language_vowel_count', 'origin', 'other.test1', 'other.test2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import json
csv = """"[{'name': 'French', 'vowel_count': 3}, {'name': 'Dutch', 'vowel_count': 4}, {'name': 'English', 'vowel_count': 5}]",Germanic,ABC,DEF"""
csv = re.split('(?![^)(]*\([^)(]*?\)\)),(?![^\[]*\])',csv)
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(csv[0].replace("'",'"')[1:-1]))
df['Origin']=csv[1]
df['other.test1']=csv[2]
df['other.test2']=csv[3]
df
```

[image]